# How to generate Junit output report using Behave Python

Tags: python, testing, junit

I'm using Behave on Python to test a web application.
My test suite run properly, but I'm not able to generate junit report.

Here is my behave.ini file :

```
    [behave]
junit=true
format=pretty
```

I only run behave using this command :`behave`

After run, the test result is print in the console, but no report is generated.

```
1 feature passed, 3 failed, 0 skipped
60 scenarios passed, 5 failed, 0 skipped
395 steps passed, 5 failed, 5 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 10m17.149s
```

What can I do ?

Comment: I observe something similar with behave `1.2.5`. I get the report when all scenarios pass, but no report as soon as there's a failure.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
behave --junit
```

on the command line instead of just `behave`.

Also, you can show the options available by using:

```
behave --help
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't change the working directory in your `steps` definition (or, at the end of the test change it back to what it was before). 
I was observing the same problem, and it turned out that the `reports` directory was created in the directory I changed into while executing one of the steps.

What *may* help, if you don't want to care about the working directory, is setting the `--junit-directory` option. This should help behave to figure out where to store the report, regardless of the working directory at the end of the test (I have not tested that though)

Comment: Your answer makes sense but here the Question is about the behave.ini file entry and whether its correct?

Answer (score -2):

I have done a bit of searching and it appears that the easiest way to do this is via the Jenkins junit plugin.

It seems to me like there ought to be a simple way to convert junit xml reports to a human readable html format, but I have not found it in any of my searches. The best I can come up with are a few junit bash scripts, but they don't appear to have any publishing capability. They only generate the xml reports.

Comment: Jenkins needs junit XML to generate behave report. This question was about `behave` not generating the report even though `--junit` option was set.